# Pod installation Failed || React native || Mac M1 Montesory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, macos, apple-m1

**POD Install**

```
showing Error in Terminal



/opt/homebrew/bin/pod: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod: 
/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
/opt/homebrew/bin/pod: line 2: 
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod: Undefined error: 0
```

Tried Below Steps

1. sudo pod-install --allow-root ==> sudo: pod-install: command not found 2. sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi ==> ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError) 3. arch -x86_64 pod install ==> /opt/homebrew/bin/pod: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod: /opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory /opt/homebrew/bin/pod: line 2: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod: Undefined error: 0

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use reactjs in Framework with basic principle being

- Your framework allows template
- Your template includes reactjs code as compiled bundles

For Spring you have ThymeLeaf which will help you in reactjs integration using templates.
For compiling reactjs code in bundles Webpack is one of the good tools to use.

You can refer this for a example : https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/